# Optimal data structure to access items near the highest value?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, tree, heap

I'm working on something where I have to store a fairly large number of items (on the order of a few thousand).

Items will be inserted, deleted, and accessed with high frequency; however, the larger an item's value, the more likely it is to be inserted, deleted, or accessed.

Furthermore, I want to support very quick sorting of the first "k" items in the structure, where "k" is fairly small.

So, ideally, the cost of doing these operations will be directly correlated to their value.

A plain old linked list where items are always kept sorted would be the naive approach here, but performance in all cases is still important; I would ideally like operations to be better than O(n) in the general case.

I've brainstormed quite a bit on this issue, and I'm stumped.

I thought at first that a [Beap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beap) might be the ideal data structure, but searches aren't biased towards the top of the beap; they instead start at a bottom corner and work their way over and upwards.  Not what I need.

A binary search tree of some flavor doesn't seem to be the right solution, because although these operations are O(log n) I'd like to do better for larger values.

What I need is almost a binary search tree flipped on its side, so that I can start traversals from the lower-right.  But I'm trying to wrap my head around that to see if it would even work for me.  I *think* it would provide O(2 log n) worst-case performance, and better than O(log n) for larger values... but I'm not entirely sure.

Is there such a data structure?  Or would I have to invent one?

Comment: Hashing? It is amortized O(1) for insertion, deletion and access.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention, I also need to partially sort the data set, to a depth of k (where k is on the order of tens of items). A hash doesn't lend itself to sorting...

Comment: Please edit your question, then. Since the problem would require different solution.

Answer (score 1):

If probabilistic data structures are acceptable, use (slightly modified) [Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Elements should be stored in decreasing order. Also search operation should be modified to start search at the head element in the bottom list (not in the top list as for normal skip list).

Expected time for insert/delete/search operations is O(log K), where K is the number of elements larger than the inserted/deleted/searched one. Worst case time complexity is O(K).

Comment: In my particular case, though, won't there be an overabundance of higher-level nodes near the front of the list because the front experiences more inserts and removals?

Comment: @user1274193: Not at all. Higher-level nodes are evenly distributed over the list because node level does not depend on the number of inserts/deletes, it depends only on random number generated while node is created.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)? They store largest items closer to the top and support all operations in sublinear time. Also, [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), which is obviously based on heaps, allows to partially sort your array (take top N elements) very quickly.